# Resolve folder path in java

Tags: java, path, directory

I am storing some files in My Documents folder in Windows 8. These files are to be opened in java. But if I transfer this project to another system, the directory path will be invalidated because it will not have same user name.
So I thought using directory name as C:\users\%username%\Documents\MyWorkingDirectory
How can I resolve this path in java.

Comment: The most flexible way is to use `System.getProperty("user.home")` which returns home directory for current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the logged in user's username like this:

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

and construct your path accordingly.

Have a look at:

- [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)
- [System.getProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29)

Example: Main.java

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.name"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to get the `%HOMEDRIVE%` and `%HOMEPATHE%` windows environment variables using `System.getenv(String)` method, for example:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(System.getenv("HOMEDRIVE")+System.getenv("HOMEPATH"));
   }
}
```

This would print `C:\Users\myusername`

Comment: @ferrerverck He doesn't want Linux, he wants to store in "My Documents folder in Windows 8"

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would initialise the file path as a string befor any methods and then call that string whenever you need to connect to that file path. For I stand see below.

Final String filePath = "c:/blah blah blah/"

Alternately you could do this in sections but I prefer a final string call then just change it as need be. If you need the user to change it this can also be done In the program itself and just change the string to string instead of final.

Hope this helps.